# jQuery select :last-child of container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble selecting all the last inputs on a set of `div`s with tables inside them. [Here's a jsFiddle of my issue.](https://jsfiddle.net/3arpch8e/)

A simplified version of my HTML structure:

```
<div class=".container">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> <input /> </td>
        <td> <input /> </td> <!-- last input in container -->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- More like this -->
<div class=".container"> ...
```

So if I had 5 `.container` the resulting selection would have 5 `input`'s

I tried the following selector:

```
$('.container input:last-child')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select the last td and get its child input like:

```
var $inputs = $('.container td:last-child>input');
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bonh4r0g/

Comment: You could also use:  var $inputs = $('.container td:last-of-type > input');